# Validate facts having nested maps using drools

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

I have a class `Fact` which is a extends `java.util.HashMap` class. I am passing object of this class as fact to drools.
Now an instance of fact looks like this (Map<String, Object>):

```
{
"key1": "value"
"attributes": [{"name": "name1", "value": "value1"},{"name": "name2", "value": "value2"},{"name": "name3", "value": "value3"}...]
"locks": [{"type": "type1", "value": "value1", "attributes": {"key_a1": "val_a1""key_a2": "val_a2"...}}]
}
```

Running validations on root level entries in this map is straight forward e.g. running validations on `key1`.
Now, I want to run some validations on `attributes` and `locks`.
For attributes, I want to ensure that all attributes which are needed are present in this map and their corresponding values are correct. So I do this in the when block:

```
fact: Fact(this["key1"] != null && this.containsKey("attributes"));
attributesEntries: Entry(key == "attributes") from fact.entrySet();
attributesMaps: LinkedHashMap() from attributesEntries;
```

fact is `HashMap`
attributes are of type `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>` (an `id` key is also added for the `LinkedHashMap` whose value is the value of key name only).
locks are of type `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>`
locks have attributes of type Map<String, String>

but it is not working. When I evaluate `attributesEntries` it is `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>` and it has all the expected values but `attributesMaps` comes as empty. I also tried passing filters like `LinkedHashMap(key == 'key1', value == 'val1')` but that also didn't work. Tried looking for solutions and none were available for this sort of structure. Whatever was available I tried to extend but didn't work.
Is this possible to achieve and if so how? Also, how do I validate value (not empty and matches a pattern) once I am able to get it from the `Map`.

I am new to drools and we are using 5.4.0.Final version of drools.

Also, how can I work with the next level nested `Map` in `locks`.

Comment: Why don't you iterate the items in the root list and add the values in the working memory? In that way you can create another rule to match the children and avoid using all the from. It should be even simpler to debug it

Answer (score 0):

I once had the misfortune of working on a project where we made this same mistake and had our class extend HashMap. (Fair warning: HashMap doesn't serialize well so you're going to use a lot of extra memory.)

I'm going to assume several things about your model because you neglected to share the class definition itself.

But I'm going to assume the following, based on your example JSON:

- You have added a string value ("value") with the key "key1"
- You have added a `List<Map<String, ?>>` value (possibly a `List<Fact>`) with the key "locks"
- You have added a `List<Map<String, ?>>` value (possibly a `List<Fact>`) with the key "attributes"

The HashMap's `get(key)` method will return an object value; you've already noted the special `this[ key ]` syntax.

From your partial rule attempt, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. I *think* you're trying to get the `List<Map<String, ?>>` that is saved in your map under the "attributes" key.

```
rule "Do something with the attributes"
when
  $fact: Fact( this["key1"] != null,
               $attr: this["attributes"] != null )
then
  System.out.println("Found " + $attr.size() + " attributes");
end
```

`this["attributes"]` returns the value associated with the key attributes. In this case, it's a List or whatever you shoved in there. If the key doesn't exist, the null check handles that.

You also asked how you could do stuff with a child map inside one of those lists. Let's say that want to do something with the attribute that has `"name": "name1"` ...

```
rule "Do something with the 'name = name1' attribute"
when
  $fact: Fact( this["key1"] != null,
               $attributes: this["attributes"] != null )
  
  $nameAttr: Map( this["name"] == "name1" ) from $attributes
then
  // do something with $nameAttr
end
```

The pattern repeats, of course. Let's say you've shoved yet another `List<Map<String, ?>>` into your attribute maps:

```
rule "Do something with a child of 'name' attribute"
when
  $fact: Fact( this["key1"] != null,
               $attributes: this["attributes"] != null )

  $nameAttr: Map( this["name"] == "name1",
                  $attrKids: this["children"] != null ) from $attributes

  $childNameAttr: Map( this["name"] == "child1" ) from $attrKids

then
  // etc.
end
```

I strongly recommend reconsidering your object model to not be Map-based. At the company I worked at where all of our projects were built against a nested Map-based model and running Drools 5.0.1, I spent significant time and effort upgrading parts of it to Drools 7 and a proper model that passed in just the data we needed. It saved a *ton* of resources and ended up being much faster.